# How to check whether a whole FormGroup is invalid (not if a single FormControl is invalid)

Tags: angular

In Angular with ReactiveForms, how do I check whether the whole FormGroup is invalid?

Comment: I actually simply just wanted to contribute knowledge to the community. I spent 15 minutes googling for this. So I thought why not post this question myself if it takes me 5 minutes, to contribute. Let me know if this is against Stackoverflow rules and why, then I will delete my question right away.

Comment: It's not against Stack Overflow rules and it's even encouraged. You did a good thing by trying to share knowledge. The comments here were wrong and you don't have to listen to them

Answer (score 0):

You declare (an unitialized) reactive form like this in the class:

```
public myReactiveForm: FormGroup;
```

Now you can just use this like this in the template:

```
<button *ngIf="myReactiveForm.invalid" ...>
```

**Additional notes:**

Actually it‘s also the same for template driven forms. Because both are actually a "FormGroup" (which actually is a subclass of AbstractControl).

For more info about FormGroup, if you want you can read the API:
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup

For more info about AbstractFormControl:
https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl

You can find the "invalid" property quickly in both links if you ctrl. + F search. A **description** of the "invalid" property is actually only under the "properties" section in AbstractControl, since this is the class that declares those properties. FormControl just inherits this "invalid" property.

Answer (score 0):

If any child FormControl or other objects that can be contained within a FormGroup has a validation error the FormGroup.invalid flag will be true.